# Dealing with conditional multiple capture regex?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm attempting to create a regex (Javascript syntax for Google Analytics) to match a specific URL type, and I can't figure out for the life of me why it's ineffective.

Given this list:

```
mysite.com/newsletter/thank-you (MATCH)
mysite.com/blog/thanksgiving-recipes (NO MATCH)
mysite.com/case-studies/thanks (NO MATCH)
mysite.com/newsletter-it/grazie-per-subscribe (MATCH)
```

I'm trying to use:

```
([^blog])(?([newsletter])(thank|grazie|obrigado|merci|gracias|dank))
```

And Regex101 is saying to take a long walk off a short pier.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the rules you're trying to implement? What makes `mysite.com/newsletter-it/grazie-per-subscribe` an expected match and the others not?

Comment: Try `/\/newsletter(?:-[a-z]{2})?\/(?:thank|grazie|obrigado|merci|gracias|dank)/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help you:

`mysite.com\/newsletter(?:-it)?\/(?:thank|grazie|obrigado|merci|gracias|dank).*`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o7zt8M/3)